# Insert into multiple tables only if record doesn't exist in primary table

Tags: mysql

I don't seem to understand `IF` statements in SQL very well.

I have two tables, one called `event_headers` and one called `event_records`. Each `event` in has a single entry in the `event_header` table and *at least one* record in the `event_records` table.

I'm running a script in c# that reads SQL files that will insert into each table, but I'm running into a problem with duplicates. I can eliminate the duplicates in the `event_header` table by using `INSERT IGNORE`. The trouble I have is I want to be able to skip inserting into the `event_records` table if there is already an entry in the `event_header` table.

EXAMPLE:

```
INSERT INTO `event_headers` (`session_id`, [...] ) VALUES ('89131', [...] );
INSERT INTO `event_records` (`event_header_session_id`, [...] )
VALUES
   ('89131', [...] ), 
   ('89131', [...] ), 
   ('89191', [...] );
```

(In truth, I have a third table that also has records that get updated, but this illustrates the point).

I want to *only* run the `INSERT` statements if the `event_headers`.`session_id` does not exist.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that in the `event_records` table, the column `event_header_session_id` will be unique? Or, if it's not, what would be the unique columns combination?

Comment: No, in the `event_headers` table the `session_id` is unique, but the `event_records` table has it's own id that is unique (not used for anything, though). The `event_header_session_id` matches a single entry in the `event_headers` table.

Comment: The last statement _"I want to only run the `INSERT` statements if the event_`headers.session_id` does not exist."_ is a bit confusing. I think you should post some sample data to illustrate the table before/after or what suppose/not suppose to be inserted.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Answer (score 0):

You must check does the 1st insertion inserts the row. You may do this, for example, using ROW_COUNT() which returns the amount of rows really altered in previous statement. The only point - you must use INSERT .. SELECT for 2nd insertion because INSERT .. VALUES does not allow WHERE clause:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO main_table VALUES (...);
INSERT INTO slave_table
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ... ) slave_data;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0668b71ddcdc67180b3ed54acb562931

Both statements must be executed as a batch (in the same connection, without any other statement between them).

Only one row must be inserted into main table.

---

But stored procedure which checks the presence in main table and inserts only when no such row is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just using VALUES, use a select:

```
INSERT INTO `event_records` (`event_header_session_id`, col_a, col_b, col_c )
SELECT event_header_session_id, col_a, col_b, col_c
FROM (
    SELECT NULL event_header_session_id, NULL col_a, NULL col_b, NULL col_c WHERE 0
    UNION ALL
    VALUES
       ROW('89131', 1,2,3 ), 
       ROW('89131', 2,3,4 ), 
       ROW('89191', 3,4,5 );
) new_rows
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM event_headers
    WHERE event_headers.session_id=new_rows.event_headers_session_id
);
```

The `SELECT NULL...UNION ALL` is the most portable way I know to name the columns of a VALUES table constructor.  On mariadb, omit the `ROW`s.